# SwiftUI: VStack don't apply to white background color but every other color

Tags: colors, swiftui, vstack

I have following code. If I change `.background(Color.green)` to `.background(Color.white)` for the VStack the background will be the systemGray I used for the Listbackground.

Has it something to do with the `.colorMultiply(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))` property?.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Bla bla bla")
                Group {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Server address", text: $serverAddress)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                    TextField("Server port", text: $serverPortString)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(8)

// Some more elements
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Connect your Server", displayMode: .large)
        }
        .colorMultiply(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
        .onTapGesture {
            self.hideKeyboard()
        }
```

White background that get ignored:

[image: White background that get ignored]

Working green background:

[image: Working green background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.colorMultiply()` adds a color multiplication effect to the view that it is applied on, meaning that it tints it the color that you have added. As your `NavigationView` is the containing view, all views inside it will be tinted `systemGray4`.

When you set it to `white`, the `systemGray4` tints that so that it blends in with the background as that is also `white`.

---

You could do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var serverAddress: String = ""
    @State var serverPortString: String = ""

    let backgroundColor = Color.init(UIColor.systemGray4)

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // or you could set this to systemGray4 and ignore the ZStack
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                backgroundColor.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                List {
                    Text("Bla bla bla")
                    .listRowBackground(backgroundColor)

                    Group {
                        VStack {
                            TextField("Server address", text: $serverAddress)
                                .keyboardType(.default)
                            TextField("Server port", text: $serverPortString)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(backgroundColor)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)


                    // Some more elements
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Connect your Server", displayMode: .large)

        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Which will give you this result:

[image: image of code result]

Comment: Thanks, but than how do I change the background color? Because just .background(Color.white) doesn't modify anything. And         UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor isn't nice I think.

Comment: I have added some code to my answer. I think to get the result that you want you will need to manipulate the `UITableView.appearance()`

Comment: Thanks :) But isn't there an other way without globally change the UITableView appearance? I think to manipulate it this way isn't a "clean" way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately at this time there isn't another way to do it. You could change the `UITableView.appearance()` in `onAppear` and then reset it in `onDisappear`, rather than change it in the `init`.